# How to simulate / script for AD integrated SSO Login in k6 tool

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

Application uses SSO login for access.

If SSO login doesn't work, browser asks for credentials in order to login to the application.

For load testing such application with K6 tool, I am trying to understand how this can be scripted for successful login.

I have tried to pass the credentials as part of the URL as in below code and trying as NTLM authentication.

Below is my script;

```
const username = "global\\user001", 
    password = "Password";

let pURL="abc.xyz.dev";

let req, res;
req = [{
 "method": "get",
 "url": `https://${username}:${password}@${pURL}/pqrs`,
 "params": {
  "headers": {
   "Host": ""+pURL+"",
   "Connection": "keep-alive",
   "Pragma": "no-cache",
   "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36",
   "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
  },
  "auth":"ntlm",
 }
}];
res = http.batch(req);
```

The expected HTTP status code for the response is 301 but I currently getting a 401: Unauthenticated.

However, if the URL in above request is changed to:

```
"url": `https://${username}:${password}@${pURL}/pqrs`,
```

I am getting error (below) as it cannot accept the username with another domain mentioned with it.

> `ERRO[0002] GoError: parse https://global\user001:Password@abc.xyz.dev/pqrs: net/url: invalid userinfo`

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `\` in your username, so you will need to url encode it.
You can use `encodeURI` as shown below:

```
import http from "k6/http";

const username = encodeURI("global\\user001"),
            password = "Password";
export default function() {

    let pURL="httpbin.org";

    let req, res;
    req = [{
         "method": "get",
         "url": `https://${username}:${password}@${pURL}/basic-auth/${username}/${password}`,
         "params": {
               "headers": {
                      "Host": ""+pURL+"",
                      "Connection": "keep-alive",
                      "Pragma": "no-cache",
                      "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
                      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36",
                      "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
                      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                      "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
                     },
               "auth":"ntlm",
              }
    }];
    res = http.batch(req);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(res[0].body));
}
```